# Ubuntu installation takes an hour. Is there any way to see logs?

Tags: system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 15.10 on my computer. It has been more than an hour. Is it normal? (I checked the option download the updates during the installation). Is there any way to see logs during the installation to be sure that it's still installing or downloading updates?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This question made me curious so I tested it out by myself and answer is... YES you can.

Go to non-graphical mode by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>F1</kbd>.
Login with default username `ubuntu` and password is blank. Now you can access `/var/log/` and see what's going on.

Since you want to check your installation process, then `tail` installer debug log:

```
tail -f /var/log/installer/debug
```

Switch back to the graphical interface with: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04 to reach console while midstream doing alongside install ctrl-alt-2 on upward then not 7 but ctrl-alt-1 to toggle back to see ongoing install

Answer (score 1):

In the newer Ubuntu releases, if you install using autoinstall config via cloud-init, the installer log is `curtin-install.log` not `debug`.

```bash
less /var/log/installer/curtin-install.log
```

or

```bash
tail -f /var/log/installer/curtin-install.log
```