# Installing Ubuntu takes more than 8 hours

Tags: system-installation, 18.04

I try to install **Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS**.

[image]

but after more than 8 hours the installation still is not finished.

Before, I chose **Normal Installation**, **Download updates while installing Ubuntu**, and **Install third-party software**.

As **Download updates while installing Ubuntu** need internet connection, I had connect to internet:

[See Speedtest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YF6Y4.png)

I think my internet is quite smooth, or do I need a faster internet connection than 10Mbps to download the software updates..?

I use **Dell Inspiron** and Here is my laptop specs:

[image]

I have tried to reinstall it many times, re-download the Ubuntu from the [official website](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), but the installation time is still too long and it does not finish.

So.. how to solve this problem..?

Comment: 10mbps should be fine, same for your specs. There seems to be another issue. Is the first image where it's stuck ?

Comment: and no, this is not normal. Installation usually finished in 15 or 20 minutes for me ...

Comment: Try to open a terminal and run `tail -f /var/log/installer/debug` while installing as suggested by [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/758089/ubuntu-installation-takes-an-hour-is-there-any-way-to-see-logs). If that works, add the output to your question.

Comment: Here is the output:
https://paste.opensuse.org/13110635

Comment: try turning off internet and installing it offline. after installation then update and upgrade. in my case slow internet during installation was causing the delay

Comment: 1. Try to compare checksum of downloaded iso, 2. try another usb stick, maybe this one is corrupt.

Comment: Thanks @RoVo and ptetteh227 for responding to my question, i had solve this by turning off my internet like ptetteh227 suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue by turning off my internet connection during installation as [ptetteh227 suggested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094261/installing-ubuntu-takes-more-than-8-hours#comment1801868_1094261).

Maybe I got this issue because of an internet connection problem while running updates during installation.