Installing ubuntu 24.04 hangs after choosing disk layout
I'm trying to install Ubuntu 24.04 on Asus x550 laptop (which already has Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows). After choosing the disk layout and proceeding to the installation step, it hangs at "copying files". The last terminal output is:
ubuntu subiquity_log.3995[9861]: finish: cmd-apt-config: success: curtin command apt-config

I found this question Ubuntu 24.04 (Nomble Numbat) hangs on installation, and I tried to disable WiFi, but it didn't work. I can't format the disk as it contains important and large data that cannot be copied.
I don't know what to do?
Regards

You might be able to find more log information using these tips: https://askubuntu.com/questions/758089/ubuntu-installation-takes-an-hour-is-there-any-way-to-see-logs

May not be the best solution. But this is what worked for me:
I connected to the internet. Then, started the installer. Selected all default options. I DID NOT check the options for downloading third party soft and media codecs. The install went forward and right at the page of Entering credentials it got stuck. I disconnected the internet. Pressed Back. And selected my drive once again and went ahead with no internet. The installer succeeded.
